# Animating the scale of image view with a .scaleAspectFill content mode during custom transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have two view controllers. Both of them contain image views, and their content modes are `.scaleAspectFill`.

I use custom transitioning animation for a modal segue from the first view controller to the second one. During the animation I add another image view on top of the  first one in the first view controller and scale it up until it covers the whole screen. The second view controller contains an image view, which covers the whole screen, so at the end of the transition I remove the temporary one.

Here is the code for the transition in the animator (`originFrame` is the frame of the image view in the first view controller):

```
 func handleImageViewAnimations(completion: @escaping (()->Void)) {
    guard let containerView = containerView, let toView = toView else {
        return
    }

    let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: originFrame)
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true



    containerView.addSubview(imageView)
    containerView.insertSubview(toView, aboveSubview: imageView)
    toView.alpha = 0.0

    containerView.bringSubview(toFront: imageView)



    let xFactor = toView.frame.width / originFrame.width
    let yFactor = toView.frame.height / originFrame.height


    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:xFactor, y:  yFactor)
        imageView.center = toView.center
    }) { (_) in
        imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
        imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        toView.alpha = 1.0
    }

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

However, because the content mode of the image views is `.scaleAspectFill` the end of the animation isn't smooth. This is happening because in that content mode images are shown differently in the image views based on their bounds. The animation basically stretches the image view, however, it doesn't take into account that different portions of the image are visible based on an image view's bounds size. The gif below shows what I mean:

[image]

This animation, with images views that have `.scaleToFill` content mode, works just fine, however, I would like to implement it with `scaleAspectFill` mode.

If you know how to make the animation smooth, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Same issue. Any resolution?

Comment: The same issue...

Answer (score 0):

apparently re-setting the UIImageView's contentMode property does the trick. It doesn't matter if you are setting the same value, UIKit will get the intent and animate it to fit the new frame properly.

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```